# Android Actionbar Icon Drawable

Tags: android, icons, drawable, density-independent-pixel

As you probably know, there are some icons on [Github](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) from Google to use. I wanted to implement a actionbar icon and saw this [here(google.com/design)](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons) and [this(dev.android.com)](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar).

- google.com/design tells me to use a 24dp icon
- dev.android.com sais I should use a 32dp icon

I myself implemented the 24dp one since it had a 24dp icon in the provided icons of Google. I put the icon in every folder by hand including xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi but as you can see below the list-icon should be bigger as it is right now. (the list-icon ist the one below the battery icon)

So I checked out [IO Schedule](https://github.com/google/iosched) and there they have a 96px x 96px icon in a xxhdpi folder which totally confused me.

1. which information is true? How should I implement my Icons? What's best practice?
2. Any advice on automate all the icon versions? thanks

[image: 24dp list icon]

Comment: Please understand the difference between the full image asset and its optical square. The overall image (including the empty space aroud the icon) is 32*32 px at 160 dpi (mdpi). The **optical square** (the image iteslf, without taking in account the empty space) is 24*24 px at 160 dpi (mdpi). Reference: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Answer (score 0):

Use 24dp icons. This will give you following real image sizes:

- mdpi icons are 24x24 (base)
- hdpi icons are 36x36 (1,5x base)
- xhdpi icons are 48x48 (2x base)
- xxhdpi icons are 72x72 (3x base)
- xxxhdpi icons are 96x96 (4x base)

In correct folders these will produce a 24dp image on appropriate screens.

Comment: As you can see the Icon I chose is what you recommended but it's too mall, something is still wrong!

Comment: Then try thr 36dp icons. The material design spec is not a law. Bend the rules